# Natural problem in S2P not known to be in any smaller class

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Is there a decision problem in $\textsf{S}_2\textsf{P}$ that (presumably) requires the full power of $\textsf{S}_2\textsf{P}$-computations? Specifically, is there a language in $\textsf{S}_2\textsf{P}$ that doesn't obviously belong to any 'natural' smaller class? The two 'natural' classes that I have in mind are $\textsf{P}^{\textsf{NP}}$ and $\textsf{BPP}$.

Comment: Are you asking for a complete problem, or just for a natural problem not known to lie in any smaller natural class?

Comment: Under plausible assumptions, $\mathrm{P^{NP}=S_2P=ZPP^{NP}}$.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow the latter, a natural problem not known to lie in any smaller class.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I guess my question is analogous to the following - under plausible assumptions, $\textsf{BPP}=\textsf{P}$, yet we have a problem that's known to be in $\textsf{BPP}$ but not in $\textsf{P}$ (polynomial identity testing or something similar). Do we know a similar example for $\textsf{S}_2\textsf{P}$ and $\textsf{P}^{\textsf{NP}}$, even though they're plausibly equal?

Comment: You might re-title your question as "Natural problem in S_2 P not known to be in any smaller class"

Comment: Also, asking for a problem not known to be in $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}} \cup \mathsf{BPP}$ would be quite different, potentially, than asking for a problem not known to be in [$\mathsf{O_2 P}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:O) (which seems much closer to $\mathsf{S_2 P}$...

Comment: Another natural class included in S2P is $P^{MA}$ (which includes both BPP and $P^{NP}$).

Comment: @Joshua Since O2P is included in P/poly, I'd say it's actually rather far from S2P.

Comment: Yup, I think the reference in the answer to [A natural problem in $S_2^P$](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17819) is a good starting point for me. Thank you!